# How to disable the Start Menu stretching animation in Windows 10 1607?

Tags: windows-10-v1607

I've recently updated Windows 10 to the anniversary edition (1607) and immediately noticed a new "feature" that whenever I open the Start Menu, the contents of it is briefly stretched vertically.

Now maybe it's just me but it got old fast.

Hence my question: *how can I disable this effect*?

Comment: @fixer1234 ok... but there are a whopping 2 followers of [tag:windows-10-v1607]...

Comment: Have you tried turning off animations (first 2 options in Visual Effect settings)?

Comment: The v1607 tag is pretty new.  Followers aren't necessarily the source of most answers.  But if the question doesn't get answers or views quickly, add the Win 10 tag back in (which will bump the question).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to turn off animations:

> Go to Settings
>
> Click on Ease of Access
>
> Select Other Options
>
> Now turn off "Play animations in Windows"

It will turn off all the animations in windows including the start menu animation.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But is there a way to turn off just the start menu animation?

Comment: @rustyx I couldn't find any. I'm sure that there will be a way to do so.